# jquery change colors on dynamically created table by content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that is used to load a dynamically generated table.

So far I can generate the table and by using `on("click" or "mouseover", function)` achieve results but I need the table change when its loads.

At first I was using `each()` but it does not work on dynamic content so after reading more I changed it to `on().`

I don't want to click  each cell for change to occur.

Code:
Jquery

```
    $(function () {
    $("#outputDiv2").on('click', "td", function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'notconnect') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#d5d5c3');
        } else if ($(this).text() == 'connected') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#00e600');
        } else if ($(this).text() == 'disabled') {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#cc0000');
        } else if ($(this).text() == 'err-disable') {
           $(this).css('background-color', '#ff9900');
      }
  });
});
```

Example html table and script on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/frams/daknayhn/3/

Comment: Can you add a class to the dynamically generated table cells? Do you have access to the template of the HTML being generated? You could theoretically do all this via classes. Or if there's an AJAX call associated with the loading of the content, you can call the `each` loop then.

Comment: yes, i can add classes to the table, its pulled via curl and formatted on PHP then outputted to html, don't know if its the best way but its works great. there is no Ajax involve. pardon my ignorace but how will doing this by classes be any diferent?

Comment: use `delegate` instead of `on` event binder. but its not recommanded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css classes for each type and when you dynamically create the table rows you can just assign the respective class for each row

```css
.connected
{
  background-color: #00e600
  
}

.err-disable
{
  background-color: #ff9900
  
}

.disabled
{
  background-color: #cc0000
  
}

.notconnect
{
  background-color: #d5d5c3
  
}
```

```html
<div id="outputDiv2">
  <table border="1">
    <tbody id="tableD">
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Port</a></td>
        <td nowrap="">Name</td>
        <td nowrap="">Status</td>
        <td nowrap="">Vlan</td>
        <td nowrap="">Duplex</td>
        <td nowrap="">Speed </td>
        <td nowrap="">Type
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/1</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="connected" >connected</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap="">10 </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/2</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="connected">connected</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap="">10 </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/3</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="notconnect">notconnect</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap=""> auto </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/4</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="notconnect">notconnect</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap=""> auto </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/4</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="notconnect">notconnect</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap=""> auto </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/4</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="err-disable">err-disable</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap=""> auto </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap=""><a href="#'">Fa0/4</a></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="" class="disabled">disabled</td>
        <td nowrap="">1</td>
        <td nowrap="">auto</td>
        <td nowrap=""> auto </td>
        <td nowrap="">10/100BaseTX
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, the problem is that the status (connected,disabled,etc) depends on the source of the output  they are not static so i would still need to make a script on PHP o assign classes to each status depending on the output.

Comment: Yes you can assign them based on the record types you are retrieving when you build your table dynamically either from PHP or jquery depending on how you implemented your code.

Comment: Well my problem is solve, turns out i did not have to use jquery after all. i just passes the same variable that created that part of the table as a class and using css provided by KAD its working like a charm. Also thanks to litel he was also on track. i was so fixated on doing it with jquery that i did not stop to think. but still i love to find a way to do it on jquery for future code.

Answer (score 1):

please try this code

```
$(function () {
    $("#outputDiv2").delegate('click', "td", function () {
       $('.notconnect').css('background-color', '#d5d5c3');
       $('.connected').css('background-color', '#00e600');
       $('.disabled').css('background-color', '#cc0000');
       $('.err-disable').css('background-color', '#ff9900');
  });
});
```